# Put in natural order lines of txt file

Tags: php

Good morning everyone, from the internet, I download a text file that contains many links to TV shows and movies streaming channels, but it is presented in a random order, there is a way in php for reordering each line according to an order that I can set I perhaps through an array or something?
This is an example of how compound and the file to which would give a different order, using the name of the channel tv, being the only source that changes in all rows. They are a beginner and are days I look for in network how to do, but I can not find examples that make my case. Thank you.

```
 <a href='http://example.com:80/tv/example/playlist.m3u8'>AdamTV</a>
 <a href='http://example.com:80/tv/example/playlist.m3u8'>Skynews</a>
 <a href='http://example.com:80/tv/example/playlist.m3u8'>NaturalTV</a>
 <a href='http://example.com:80/tv/example/playlist.m3u8'>SportTV</a>
 <a href='http://example.com:80/tv/example/playlist.m3u8'>Channel4</a>
```

This is what I'm trying to do, start reading the file line by line, but I error Deprecated: Function split () is deprecated

```
<?php
$linee = file("file.txt");
while(list(,$value) = each($linee)) {
list($url, $channel) = split("[>]", $value);
$params["url"] = trim($url);
$params["channel"] = trim($channel);
echo $params["url"]."   ".$params["channel"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Read file into array and then sort the array with [usort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) - this will allow to you extract a TV show name from a link (for example, with `preg_match`) and compare them.

**Example:**

```
$linee = [
    "<a href='http://example.com:80/tv/example/playlist.m3u8'>AdamTV</a>",
    "<a href='http://example.com:80/tv/example/playlist.m3u8'>Skynews</a>",
    "<a href='http://example.com:80/tv/example/playlist.m3u8'>NaturalTV</a>",
    "<a href='http://example.com:80/tv/example/playlist.m3u8'>SportTV</a>",
    "<a href='http://example.com:80/tv/example/playlist.m3u8'>Channel4</a>",
];

usort(
    $linee,
    function($a, $b) {
        preg_match("/>(.*)</", $a, $a_val);
        preg_match("/>(.*)</", $b, $b_val);
        
        if ($a_val[0] == $b_val[0]) {
            return 0;
        }
        return ($a_val[0] < $b_val[0]) ? -1 : 1;
    }
);

print_r($linee);
```

Comment: Honestly, I'm really inexperienced, you can take an example of how I can do, grazie.Sono days I try and I try script to fit my needs, but to no avail

Comment: Please, edit your post with code of your attempt. Otherwise I doubt you will get any help here.

Comment: I modified the original post, as suggested putting the work done up to now, thanks

Comment: I added a simple example. Not sure that it is exactly what you need, but it illustrates my approach.

Comment: thank you for the example, but my goal is to read the txt file line by line and rewrite the txt file by changing the order of the lines based on my choice and not the one set by those who made up the original file. Ade example to overwrite a file by reversing the first with the second line